# I have a circuit which draws a current of 500mA, and works at 5V. I require it to draw max of 200uA from the supply

Tags: current, power-electronics, optoelectronics

I have a smoke detector circuit which draws a current of 500mA, and works at 5V. I require it to draw not more than 200uA from the supply. Will a simple current limiter circuit solve this problem?
also the input supply to the detector will be 18-30 V, but at these values, the LED's used will burn. So if i use a voltage regulator, will it suffice? kindly suggest what can be used/done. Im not sure if the answer is as simple as i think it could be, or if there are more complications to it!

---

The basic circuit is [**from here**](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/need-help-for-infrared-indicator.73868/)

[image]

but I'm using dual LED's, one blue and one IR in parallel. I'm using a microcontroller to pulse between red and blue alternatively, and simulataneously record the readings. The photodiode resistance is 10k ohm. I hope the information is sufficient. Basically the power required is to drive the led's, so I'm assuming a lesser value should be sufficient.

[**This is a similar concept but with a photo transistor sensor rather than a photodiode sensor.**](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/need-help-for-infrared-indicator.73868/)

[image]

The LED resistors are 100 ohm.
I also wanted to know, if we limit the current to this circuit to 200uA, does the remaining current get diverted/dissipated elsewhere, or does only 200uA get drawn from the supply? because I would prefer the latter.

Comment: There are several ways you could limit the current to 200uA but if your circuit requires 500mA at 5V, 2.5W then you wont have 5V any more and the circuit is unlikely to work.  Post details of the circuit so we can advise if it is possible to reduce the power requirement.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert 200uA at 18-30V to 500mA at 5V? That's completely impossible, unless you're okay with the device being *off* 99.9% of the time, in which case you can "save up" energy and use it in short bursts. Or are you asking how to modify a circuit so it uses less power?

Comment: @immibis Its a 500mA supply, but i want my circuit to only draw a max of 200uA... so to answer ur question, yes, i want to modify or most probably add a circuit before this to limit its power consumption

Comment: @ConanReynolds If your circuit uses 200uA, it will use 200uA, even when connected to a supply capable of producing 500mA. (Assuming the voltage is okay)

Comment: If you limit the current to 200uA, your LED will become extremely dim.

Comment: @immibis I understand that, what my problem is, its drawing 500mA. Im not sure whether that is required or not, if not, i want to limit the current to a max of 200uA

Comment: Conan - Vellore?

Comment: Conan - note that the photodiode sensor and phototransistor sensor shown in the two diagrams work quite differently and that the series resistor value may be quite different. The phototransistor is turned on by the LED light and a current of typically 0.1 to 10 mA flows. The photo diode is REVERSE BIASED and the light changes it reverse bias leakage current which is usually much lower that the photo transistor current. It is common to use such diodes in the feedback path of an opamp - a look at web examples would be instructive.

Comment: Look at the pages linked to relevant examples [**shown here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=pin+diode+photodetectors&biw=1422&bih=998&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU0pWP65nKAhUCn6YKHWnkDqcQ_AUIBigB&dpr=0.9#tbm=isch&q=pin+diode+photodetector+circuit+opamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem here is that you are giving us part of the problem and solutions that you think or hope may work. MUCH better is to tell us what you want (completely) and we'll give you what you need. (Guitar sounds off ...).

That said:

The LED will draw decreasing current with increasing resistance.
Photodetector output will fall with decreasing LED current and will at some stage reach a level of response that is liable to be inadequate.

A better solution than using very low continuous current is to find the minim7um LED current that works acceptably and then pulse the LED occasionally and sample the resultant detector output. There will be issues with response times but an arrangement should be possible which allows the desired current reduction.

It is not obvious where you get the 500 mA current figure from, or why.  If you use 100 Ohm resistors and 30V supply, as you suggest. then current will be about i = V/R ~= 30/100 = 300 mA **BUT** there is absolutely no need to run the LED at that current. By limiting LED current to say 10 mA, at 18V you will need R = V/I = (18-V_LED)/I ~= 1600 Ohms. This will draw about 28 mA at 30V.  Actual LED current can be adjusted to suit.

If LED current was say 10 mA when on the running it at a 1:50 on:off cycle would yield 200 uA mean.

The photodiode current will be low as it is reverse biased but you will have to ensure that diode V_max_applied does not exceed its specifications.

Comment: thank you sir, made a lot of sense. I might have to change my resistor values, and check again keeping in mind the Vmax. and as far as LED pulsing is concerned, I am doing that using the micro controller, though it is being turned on and off at a ratio of 1:1. I shall try the on:off at a lower ratio this time